# How to make a Traversable Tree Data Structure in C

Tags: c, tree, linked-list, treenode, traversal

Does anyone have any good examples of building a tree data structure both iteratively and recursively in C Language (!C++)? Also to traverse through the tree and cover every node..

I'm likely to use this struct:

```
typedef struct treeNode *treeLink;
struct treeNode {
    Item item;
    treeLink left, right;
};
```

Comment: Is this also likely to be homework?

Comment: Naturally, you tried a Google search for something like [building a binary tree in C](http://www.google.co.nz/search?q=binary+tree+in+C) and reviewed the plethora of useful results prior to posting this question...

Comment: yeah its homework and im always used to arrays, i've built a small tree structure with 3 levels of random ints with pure iteration. But am right now am finding cleaner code to recursively program this binary tree without missing branches or levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
treeLink Traverse_In_Order(treeLink  current){
          if(curernt == NULL) return NULL;
          Traverse(current->left);
          operation(current->item);
          Traverse(current->right);
          return current; // in case you want to do something on this node
}


treeLink Traverse_Pre_Order(treeLink  current){
          if(curernt == NULL) return NULL;
          operation(current->item);
          Traverse(current->left);        
          Traverse(current->right);
          return current; // in case you want to do something on this node
}

treeLink Traverse_Pos_Order(treeLink  current){
          if(curernt == NULL) return NULL;
          Traverse(current->left);        
          Traverse(current->right);
          operation(current->item);
          return current; // in case you want to do something on this node
}
```